# 1С - RDP или TCP\IP

Tags: 1с

Доброго дня всем.
Возникло простое любопытство, я 1С не занимаюсь, но стало интересно про доступ к её БД.
Объясните, чем RDP доступ преимущественнее TCP\IP доступа в LAN, в работе с 1С?
Ведь по TCP\IP (LAN) передаёются лишь данные, а через RDP весь интерфейс, графика и прочее.Моё мнение, что в RDP лишь, максимум 5-10% трафика занимает передача данных.

Comment: минус за любознательность?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Уважаемый, [@I_CaR](/users/1270/i_car), с полной ответсвенностью вам заявляю, что протокол RDP (порт 3389) в качестве транспорта также использует протокол TCP/IP. В качестве протокола обмена файлами в ОС windows выступает протокол SMB который также в свою очередь использует TCP/IP. Чем принциписально отличаются протоколы RDP и SMB вы можете прочитать в Википедии, там все внятно описано.

От себя по личному отпыту могу добавить, что протокол RDP передает  хорошо упакаванное изображение экарана удаленного сервера, что в свою очередь позовляет работать с удаленным сервером через узкие канали с приемлемыми задержками. Передаваемое изображаение шифрутется а сами данные по сети фактически не передаются так как вся работа происходит на сервере в отличии от работы через LAN где бы вам пришлось передавать данные через сеть от сервера к клиенту.

Comment: @huffman;Это и понятно, что протокол TCP\IP стоит во главе, как основной для передачи данных по сети.  Но я за оптимизацию и рационализацию ресурсов сети и АРМов.  Поэтому из Вашего ответа не слишком понял, равны ли эти два подхода в работе с 1С, или же у какого-то есть преимущество?Допустим 50 АРМов, и почему одни делают доступ через RDP, а другие просто ставят клиентскую часть на АРМы и коннектятся к БД по IP в ЛВС предприятий?

Comment: 1. У Вас есть сервер с достаточно мощным железом, который выдержит несколько виртуалок (под DC, терминальный сервер, сервер лицензирования, сервер БД, сервер 1С etc), но Вы не хотите разоряться на компы рабочих мест пользователей. В этом случае Ваш выбор - RDP (если не путаю - терминальная версия 1С), поскольку Вы можете себе позволить достаточно сильно нагрузить ***именно сервер***.2. У Вас НЕТ сервера из п.1, роль сервера 1С выполняет обычный офисный компик средней паршивости. И Вы НЕ можете себе позволить больших нагрузок на этот "сервер". И тогда Ваш выбор - расшареная база.

Comment: Определенно преимущество у RDP и вот почему:1. Сервер 1С находится как правило на выделенном сервере за счет этого скорость работы 1С на порядок выше. 2. Доступ к серверсу можно организовать любому клиенту как в офисе так и из за его приделами.3. Единая плитика безопасности на уровне AD как к локальным так и к удаленным пользователям.4. Безопасность5. Нет необходимости устанавливать и настраивать клиента 1С на рабочей станции пользователя.Доступ к 1С через RDP я на практике использую с 2003 года с момента выхода серверной версии windows 2003. Решерие проверено временем.

Comment: При выборе п.2 Ваш трафик не шифруется (без дополнительных действий со стороны пользователей) и, если вдруг понадобится доступ не из офиса с "сервером", может быть перехвачен, использован etc... По сути - это обычная файлопомойка.При выборе п.1 можно ограничить пользователей ТОЛЬКО 1С-кой, и без доп. умений доступак непосредственно к фалам базы они не получат. +, см. ответ @huffman, трафик шифруется."На пальцах": * если Ваш офис - три бухгалтера и полтора землекопа, то Ваш выбор - п.2.* если Ваш офис - куча бухгалтеров, коммерсанты и т.д., и т.п., то Ваш выбор - п.1.

Answer (score 0):

Ну RDP передаёт не весь интерфейс, а диффы, к тому же хорошо пожатые. При работе с большими базами трафика там будет меньше.

Ну и удобнее это, в конце концов - не нужно мучаться с установкой 1с на кучу машин.

Answer (score 0):

Тут возникает вопрос о какой платформе 1с мы говорим? Если о платформе 8.1, то почти все вышесказанное верно. Если же мы говорим о платформах 8.2 или 8.3 и работе в режиме тонкого клиента или веб-клиента, то позволю себе не согласиться. Во-первых все работы по обеспечению визуального отображения данных берет на себя клиентская машина (с помощью тонкого клиента и используя веб браузер при работе через веб клиент), а обработкой данных занимается сервер/сервера на которых располагается сервер приложений 1с, сервер БД и, при необходимости, веб сервер. Передача данных осуществляется с использованием протокола SSL, то есть используется шифрование данных.

Answer (score 0):

Еще это вопрос экономический, с появлением управляемых форм RDP стало очень дорого.

Answer (score 0):

Знание модели OSI будет Вам в помощь.